# Import material design icons into Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, material-ui

I'm downloading icons from the material design website, for each icon it gives me 4 images each for hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi. What's the best way to go about importing these into an Android Studio project so they go into the proper folder structure?

The 4 variations are 18, 24, 36, and 48 dp. They're downloaded from https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: go to materialdesignicons.com and it has a vector drawable export option